# PHP-MySql: Like Query with modified Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a column in a database table with a code LIKE this: `12 34 56`

In my php page I have a text form for find the code AND the query is:

```
SELECT column as colmn_find FROM CER WHERE column LIKE '%".$term."%';
```

How I search the code also without the white spaces?

So if i find 12 34 is the same of 1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column as colmn_find 
FROM CER 
WHERE REPLACE(column, ' ', '') LIKE '%YOURTERM%';
```

Replace the spaces in your where clause with nothing and it will be treated as if it had no spaces in your search.